# Ubuntu 15.04 NVIDIA Drivers

Tags: nvidia

I am trying to install NVIDIA drivers (NVIDIA GForce 210) to my Ubuntu Linux 15.04 [32bit]. The download file is a .run file, and the only thing online I've found was to do in terminal:

```
cd Downloads
chmod +x [name].run
sudo ./[name].run
```

I added sudo to the command because after running, it tells me it needs to be run as root. After running this ^ however, it tells me the drivers cannot install because I'm running an X Server. What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo service lightdm stop`

Then a console appears and you can try again.

It's better if you write commands in a console that you can start by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: I tried that first command and an interface showed up but nothing happened... And I used Ctrl+Alt+F1 but it still said I was running X Server..

Comment: And also if this does close X Server how do I exit this interface?

Comment: It's the CLI interface. After installation you must restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend installing drivers from .run files.

They will stop working after first kernel update.

You can install Nvidia drivers by

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```